# Entity Framework Core one-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to learn EF Core. I want to define a one-to-one relationship between `Employee` and `Payroll` as well as between `Employee` and `Address`.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } = 
    public DateOnly DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; } 
    public string Position { get; set; } 
    public long Salary { get; set; }
    public DateOnly HireDate { get; set; }
    public DateOnly? TerminationDate { get; set; }
    //
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; } 
    public Payroll Payroll { get; set; } 
    public Address Address { get; set; } 
    public List<Asset>? Assets { get; set; }
}

public class Payroll
{
    public int PayrollId { get; set; }
    public long BaseSalary { get; set; }

    // 
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; } 
    public string City { get; set; } 
    public string State { get; set; } 
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; } 
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; } 
}
```

But when I generate the diagram in pgAdmin, it is showing one-to-many relationships.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd8bR.png)

Thanks

I tried defining the relationship but it is giving the same results.

```
public class DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : DbContext(options)
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Payroll> Payroll { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Asset> Assets { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                    .HasOne(e => e.Payroll)
                    .WithOne(p => p.Employee)
                    .HasForeignKey<Payroll>(p => p.EmployeeId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                    .HasOne(e => e.Address)
                    .WithOne(a => a.Employee)
                    .HasForeignKey<Address>(a => a.EmployeeId)
                    .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Payroll>()
                    .HasIndex(p => p.EmployeeId)
                    .IsUnique();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
                    .HasIndex(p => p.EmployeeId)
                    .IsUnique();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a one-to-one relationship joins on PKs, and in a fully normalized solution it would be recommended to do just that:

```
public class Payroll
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public long BaseSalary { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Id))]
    public Employee Employee { get; protected set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; } 
    public string City { get; set; } 
    public string State { get; set; } 
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Id))]
    public Employee Employee { get; protected set; } 
}
```

Here the Employee.Id, Payroll.Id, and Address.Id would be the exact same value for a particular employee. The mapping would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Payroll)
    .WithOne(p => p.Employee)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Address)
    .WithOne(a => a.Employee)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

It is possible to map a one-to-one relationship in EF with a defined FK as you have done correctly with the unique constraint on the FK, however as far as the database is concerned this is nothing more than a many-to-one relationship that EF will try and enforce as a one-to-one. Using the PK-to-PK relationship is recommended as there is no potential deviation allowed and the DB will see it as a true one-to-one relationship. One-to-one relationships should never change owners (I.e. an address moving from one employee to another) which is a perfectly valid scenario that can be done with a FK-based implementation, granted it satisfies the unique constraint on the FK.